# Add two colors in label text of TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, text-styling

I need to set two different colors for labelText of TextField(). I've a feature request to implement a TextField which title would show like 'Required*' but the difference I need is to set two different color for label text like green color for "Required" and red color only for '*'.

```
TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search here',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(),
                    labelText: 'Required*' //make 'Required' green and '*' red color
                  ),
                  onChanged: (str) {
                    //need to implement debounce
                  }
              )
```

Comment: I don't think flutter support it now,  you have to create a custom widget for it

Answer (score 0):

Hey it is possible to implement the scheme. But it is a little tricky. The first thing you need is a stack widget.
Inside it a TextField widget and a Positioned widget. When you enter something in the TextField, keep it in the same color for now. Then you can overwrite the desired places with Positioned Widget.
This is how I implemented it in my project earlier.
Remember, when validating the field, the position can slip. Do not disregard the edge cases.

Comment: Can you show some code? As this does not tackle the color problem so far.